# Optimize this piece of c# code

Tags: c#, optimization

Problem:Given a comma separated string of numbers, want to find out the highest average of digits of number.
for eg: consider a string of number "123,345,555" the output would be 5 since 5 is the highest average among 123,345,555.

Here is my program..in C#

```
int Max_Avg(string number_list)
{
      int i;
        Int32 sum;
        Int32 max_avg = 0;
        int limit = 0;
        string[] num = number_list.Split(',');
        limit = num.Length;
        while (limit-- > 0)
        {
                i=0;
                sum = 0;
                while (i < num[limit].Length)
                {
                    sum += Convert.ToInt32(num[limit].Substring(i, 1));
                    i++;
                }
                int tmp=sum / num[limit].Length;
                if (tmp > max_avg)
                {
                    max_avg = tmp;
                }
        }
         return max_avg;
}
```

If any can one can optimize its performance or suggest a more optimised approach to speed it up .....

Comment: Optimize in terms of what? Memory/Time complexity/performance/lines of code?

Comment: wouldnt the output be 5 (avg of 5, 5, 5)

Comment: sorry my mistake...its updated

Comment: I haven't been a good person and taken some samples, but the first thing that pops out at me is the use of `Substring`. That's going to build a new string, hitting `new` (a costly thing to do). Then it's going to try to parse that string into an integer (another costly thing to do). Then of course it has to garbage collect the string it made. It's asking a lot of an optimizer to straighten all *that* out.

Comment: You are only doing integer division for the average.  Is that really what you want?

Comment: No reason to mix Int32 and int.  For clarity, just pick one and stick with it (int).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

(optimized for maintainability / code, rather than raw performance)

```
return (int) number_list.Split(',')
       .Select(term => term.Average(c => (int) (c - '0'))).Max();
```

Comment: thats seems so cute.....can u just explain what u did dere....i'm actually new to c#

Comment: It is cure, but also slower. Depending how much data you process in how tight a loop this may be a factor slower - may or my not be ascceptable, you dont give context.

Comment: @Jay it is using the LINQ extension methods; first we take the `Split` (by comma), giving us 3 terms; then for each term, we perform a *projection* (`Select`) that takes the term string, and averages the characters, using character-math to be efficient; then the maximum of those averages is computed. I'm being a bit hazy with some ordering here, to keep it simple.

Comment: -1 - OP makes it clear he wants optimization for speed, so an answer saying it is not opimized for speed is sort of not on topic.

Comment: @TomTom meh; the *important* speed issue here was the `Convert`, which you'll notice **I DID NOT USE**; to compare beyond that, you'd need to profile very carefully. Personally, I'd wager that once the `Convert` is gone this is plenty fast enough.

Comment: ;) Dependson context. Really. I have very similar code and am now spending week 2 with a profiler to get it faster. IF that is parsing tons of data from a stream, every percent may count.

Comment: @TomTom yes, it does depend on context. Which **we don't have**.

Comment: @MarcGravell one more doubt ..what is c - '0'

Comment: Hi Marc, is the int cast on (c - '0') necessary, or is that just there for clarity?

Comment: @C.McAtackney necessity; there is no `Enumerable.Average` overload that uses `char`, and besides - at that point we are talking `int` too. The good thing is: *it doesn't matter* - the conversion between `char` and `int` is pretty much a no-op.

Comment: @Marc Gravell: It seems that the - operator when used on char returns an Int32 anyway though, not a char.

Comment: @C.McAtackney oh, fine, in that case "for clarity" ;p

Comment: @Jay - a char is a unicode code-point; the code-point `'a'` has the value 97, for example. Since we are talking about characters in the range `'0'` (=48) to `'9'` (=57), thus `c - '0'` is a cheeky way of getting the value represented as an integer. `'0' - '0' = 0`, `'5' - '0' = 5`, etc

Comment: @Marc Gravell: Haha, not being nit-picky, was just genuinely curious as this is the first time I've ever seen char arithmetic being used. A very neat trick to remember. As a slight tangent, I tried to crack open the System.Char type using ILSpy to see if I could look at the source for minus operator, but there doesn't seem to be a definition for it in there. Do you know where these operators are defined?

Comment: @C.McAtackney it doesn't exist; at the IL level things like `char`, `short` and `ushort` are treated as `int32` (the IL term, not `System.Int32`, although `System.Int32` also uses IL `int32`), and an IL `sub` is performed. All primitives, etc.

Answer (score 1):

The only sensible optimization for speed I see is in this line:

> Convert.ToInt32(num[limit].Substring(i, 1));

This is slow - you split the strings by character into substrings, then use a generic parser.

A sub-funnction could take a char and then make a SWITCH over the 10 valid valeus (0-9) or convert the numberic value of the char into the number directly. THhs is about all you could do. The COnvert.ToInt32 method is way too generic to be fast here, I think.

Only relevant when you do that thousands of times, but heck, I write data parsers at the moment where optimizations like that boost them up significantly.

Comment: Indeed, that should just be `(int)(num[limit][i] - '0')`

Comment: Exactly. SHould be TON faster ni a tight loop.

Comment: Actually you could also get rid of teh array and make it a pointer - another optimization ;) Unsafe priviledge required, though.

Comment: that is accessing the *string* by index, not a char-array. You *could* probably avoid the array from `split` (and the extra strings) by processing the whole string by indexer, but...

Comment: ...it is not nice? Agree. BUt sometimes milliseconds count. I parse market data and historical data loads take weeks - running in a loop that pretty much is stuff like that at parts. I was tripling the speed last week by putting in optimizations like that.

Comment: you misunderstood my comment, I think - you were commenting on "get rid of teh array and make it a pointer" - the only array here is the one from string.Split, which we *could* avoid by processing the original string directly - I just don't think there's a *lot* to be gained by using a pointer on this occasion. Would have to profile before and after, but removing that `Convert` is the **important** bit here; after that, it is small deltas

Answer (score 1):

This is my version, a little cleaner in my opinion, but probably not much faster or anything.

```
int Max_Avg(string number_list)
{
    int result = 0;
    var numbers = number_list.Split(',');
    foreach (var num in numbers)
    {
        var total = 0.0;
        foreach (var ch in num)
        {
            total += (int) ch;
        }
        var avg = total/num.Length;
        result = avg > result ? avg : result;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int Max_Avg(string number_list)
{
    var result = 0;
    var sum = 0;
    var count = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < number_list.Length; i++)
    {
       if (number_list[i] == ',')
       {
          if (count > 0)
          {
              result = math.Max(result, sum / count);
              sum = 0;
              count = 0;
          }
       }
       else
       {
          sum += number_list[i] - '0';
          count++;
       }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: This is using integer division, as in the OP's code (which seems wrong to me).